# Why can't I use Action Center?

Tags: 8.1, action-center

While switching apps I can't use the Action Center center. Why such behavior? Is it specific to my phone *(but I don't think that is the case even)*. Any idea?

**Update**

There were few instances where I wanted to get the Action Center while I was Closing the Apps/Games that I was using but then I could get it.

For first one or two times it was not an issue but it started annoying me as I had to press Back button everytime(which would get me back to the last opened App/Game)
And I would either not get or had to swipe 2-4 times, the Action Center till the App/Game loads.

Comment: What do mean "While switching apps"? do you mean whilst an app is opening, or something else?

Comment: I meant when using the App Switcher(long press of Back button)

Comment: Because it is a notification center, not an app.

Comment: What about Lockscreen and Start page? I can see the Action center there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@VivekParekh, Windows Phone 8.1 preview for developers does not support Action Center to be opened while Task Switcher is on. Don't worry, it's not your device's problem, it's just OS default behavior.

Plus Action Center can only be pushed down only when you are using an app, not while you are in Task Switcher, cause Task Switcher is not an app, its OS specified view.

Comment: You mean the Lumia Cyan update allow users to get the Action Center while switching app?

Comment: @VivekParekh I don't think that's what he's saying. Why do you want/need to use Action Centre while in the app switcher anyway?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: @VivekParekh, I didn't say Cyan OTA  update is going to cover this lagging, only #WindowsPhone platform developers can say it better. But what I have experienced in Lumia 630 (Um mentioning this device as it comes with preinstalled Cyan OTA update), it doesn't provide the feature u are intending to have.

Comment: Alright. I guess there might be a reason behind not keeping it